# Interesting quirk with the "with" keyword in javascript and parent/child windows

Tags: javascript, window, parent, with-statement, window.opener

I noticed something peculiar about the "with" keyword in javascript and the parent and child window relationship, specifically window.opener.  I haven't tested this from the parent window, just the child, but it is worth noting in the example below--

Parent window (Parent.html):

```
// global scope
function ParentFunc() { alert("I am a parent function"); }
```

Child window (Child.html):

```
// global scope
var baseWin = window.opener;

// "this" keyword corresponds to Child.html when function below is called
function Child_Onclick_Func()
{
  alert("Hi, from Child");
  with (baseWin)
  {
    ParentFunc();
    alert("Hi, from Parent");
  }
  alert("Hi, back to Child");
}
```

The "with" keyword, in this case, switches to the parent window and the second alert fires an implicit onfocus to the parent window, as well.  I didn't realize "with" would switch to the parent window, but it makes sense now.

Comment: Try to avoid using the `with` keyword... ever.  It's making an exit out of the JavaScript language.  So anything you program will break in modern browsers.

Comment: Right, thank you.  This was just an academic exercise.  I think it was created for those who avoid oop and prefer procedural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `window` is the global namespace when running javascript in a web browser. When you write:

```
alert('Hello, World!');
```

You are actually calling the `window.alert` method.